# node-postgres: [error] This socket has been ended by the other party

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I use node-protgres to manipulate the db in my nodejs app.

What I have done:

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
var dbconnect = {
    user: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx', 
    host: 'xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    port: 0000, 
    max: 20, // max number of clients in the pool
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000 
};
const pool = new Pool(dbconnect);
pool.on('error', function (err, client) {
    console.error('idle client error', err.message, err.stack)
});

function listOfPets(req, res) {

 pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
        }

        var sql =
            "SELECT * FROM pets"
        client.query(sql, function (err, result) {

                done();

                if (err) {
                    return console.error('error running query', err);
                }

                ... //Handle the result 

            });
    });

}
```

The function is working fine, however the server keep sending me the error report OK to severe. I checked the log:

> idle client error This socket has been ended by the other party Error:
>   This socket has been ended by the other party
>       at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:291:12)
>       at Connection.end (/var/app/current/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:313:22)
>       at global.Promise (/var/app/current/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:410:23)
>       at Client.end (/var/app/current/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:409:12)
>       at Pool._remove (/var/app/current/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:135:12)
>       at Timeout.setTimeout (/var/app/current/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:38:12)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)

I think the problem came from the 'done()' doesn't work or was put at wrong place.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the `pool` object inside the callback. I had a similar error with a postgres client. I solved it by declaring the `client` inside the callback for a GET request.

Have a look at this issue, it's where I found my solution: [Github issue](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/761)

Answer (score -1):

Hope this can help you =). I think you can use this link to fixed http://mherman.org/blog/2015/02/12/postgresql-and-nodejs/#.WbpNjMgjGHs

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the article. The tutorial doesn't not use pool and leads to using pg-promise instead of node-postgres.  Which one you suggest me to use? BTW, it's an useful article